# Concurrent requests overriding data in Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, hapi.js, ioredis

**Scenarios:** When ever a request comes I need to connect to Redis instance, open the connection, fetch the count, update the count and close the connect(For every request this is the flow).When the requests are coming in sequential order i.e. 1 user sending 100 requests one after the other then the count in Redis is 100.

**Issue:** Issue is when concurrent requests comes. i.e. 10 users sending 100 requests(each user 10 requests) concurrently then the count is not 100 its around 50.

**Example:** Assume count in Redis is 0. If 10 requests comes at the same time then 10 connections will be opened and all the 10 connections will fetch the count value as 0 and updated it to 1.

**Analysis:** I found out that, as the requests are coming concurrently, multiple connections are fetching the same count value and updating it because of it the count value is getting overridden. Can anyone suggest a best way to avoid this problem if you have already encountered this problem.

Here we are using Hapijs, Redis 3.0, ioredis

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend queueing each task so that each request finishes before the next one starts.

[Queue.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/queue) is a good library I have used before but you can check out others if you want.

Here is an example basically from the docs but adapted slightly for your use case:

```
var queue = require('../')

var q = queue()
var results = []

var rateLimited = false

q.push(function (cb) {
    if(!rateLimited){
        // get data and push into results
        results.push('two')
    }
  cb()
})

q.start(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('all done:', results)
})
```

This is a very loose example as I just wrote it quickly and without seeing your code base but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply. But here the use case is i need to apply rate limiting on number of requests. So here once i read the count i will check for the limit value and decide whether to process the request or reject the request.

Comment: @AnilKumarR I'm not sure why that would stop you using a queueing system. I have added some example code to my answer which may help.